# Counter through Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm developing a counter in Verilog that cycles through the following series:

```
0, 1, 3, 7, 6, 4, 0, 1, ...
```

and resets to `0` on `reset_b`.

Here is my code so far, it doesn't seem to make it past `3` in the cycle:

```
module Counter_1(output reg [2: 0] Count, input clock, reset);

    reg [2: 0] last;

    always @(posedge clock, negedge reset) begin

        if (!reset) begin
            Count <= 3'b000;
        end

        else begin

            case (last)
                3'b000: Count <= 3'b001;
                3'b001: Count <= 3'b011;
                3'b011: Count <= 3'b111;
                3'b111: Count <= 3'b110;
                3'b110: Count <= 3'b100;
                3'b100: Count <= 3'b000;
            endcase

        end

        last <= Count;

    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always useful to look at the sequence:

```
000
001
011
111
110
100
```

Analyse the pattern and you find the sequence can be made by:

```
if (!reset) 
   Count <= 3'b000;
else
   Count <= {Count[1:0],~Count[3]};
```

To follow your method: you can just use the Count as input for the next value. The usage of 'last' is not needed:

```
case (Count)
3'b000 : Count <= 3'b001;
3'b001 : Count <= 3'b011;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly be assigning last in the reset block:

```
    if (!reset) begin
        last <= 3'b000;
        Count <= 3'b000;
    end
```

I'd imagine that will fix your issue, as I don't see any other problems with your code (assuming your clock and reset inputs work correctly and you're using an active high reset).

Also, why are you including reset in your always condition? I believe that your always condition could simply be:

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
```

Comment: The reset in the always condition is an asynchronous reset. The code you are proposing gives a synchronous reset.